# Replace the contents of a div with regex match of string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to figure out how to replace the contents of a `<div>` with the results from a regex `.match()` statement on a string. This is the code I have so far but I can't get it to work. I want the button to stay on screen but the `<div>` to reflect the matched word.

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function search(){
        var str = "Visit W3Schools";
        var patt1 = /w3schools/i;
        document.write(str.replace(document.getElementById("results"),
                                   (str.match(patt1))));
    }
    </script>
</body>

<div id="results">So this is some text.</div>
<button name="Search" onclick="search()">Click Here</button>
</html>
```

Any ideas as to why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the button completing it's default event, which is to submit the page. (Edit: No it's not, its default event is nothing - assumed it was a `<submit>` :)  )

In addition, to get a div from the document basic on it's `id` attribute, you use `document.getElementById('id-of-element')` and to set the contents of a div, you use `.innerHTML` on the element we just got.

```
// We need to take the event handler as a parameter for the function, let's call it e
function search(e){
    var str = "Visit W3Schools";
    var patt1 = /w3schools/i;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = str.match(patt1)[0];
    // This line stops the default action occurring
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Note: we don't need to specify an argument here, e goes in automatically

```
<button name="Search" onclick="search()">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: To prevent the button from submitting, you can just set its `type` attribute to `button`.

Answer (score 1):

[**document.write**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) will replace the entire page with the passed in parameter. So you just want to update that single DIV, `results`. So you want to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML):

```
function search() {
    var str = "Visit W3Schools";
    var patt1 = /w3schools/i;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = str.match(patt1)[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is searching for the String `"So this is come text."` in the String `"Visit W3Schools"` and replacing it with the array `["W3Schools"]`, then writing it to the screen. This doesn't make much sense.

Try something like this instead:

```
function search(){
    var str = "Visit W3Schools";
    var patt1=/w3schools/i;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=(str.match(patt1))[0];
}
```